# Disk encryption with ecryptfs - full disk

Tags: linux, encryption, disk, disk-encryption, ecryptfs

i'm new and i hope to find an answer here. Please tell me, if you need more information.

I have an disk encryption for my home partition on Linux 4.13.0-43-generic x86_64 (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS).

Today when I started the laptop, I got the message, that my disk is full and there is no available space any more. With the disk usage analysis I saw, that the encryption directory (/home/.ecryptfs/bianca/.Private) is completly full - the other partition have enough space. 
I did not find any answer by Google, but I would like to know, if there may be encryption files, which won't be needed any more because they may be outdated or old or anything? If yes, it is possible to remove these files or directories in this directory? Is there any tool, that can delete files, if they are not used any more?

Or do you have any other recommendation, what I can do?

It would be glad, if someone made already experience with this and can share it with me.

Thank you in advance.
Bianca

**edit:**

Output of `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sr0                          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
sda                           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
├─sda2                        8:2    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda5                        8:5    0 465,3G  0 part  
│ ├─ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  15,7G  0 lvm   
│ │ └─cryptswap1            253:2    0  15,7G  0 crypt [SWAP]
│ └─ubuntu--mate--vg-root   253:0    0 449,6G  0 lvm   /
└─sda1                        8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot
```

Comment: A good tool to remove temporary or cached files and generated thumbnails and more is [`bleachbit`](https://www.bleachbit.org/). But it won't help in the long term. Move some files to the other partition (e.g. Movies, Music) or resize your partitions from a live system using `gparted`.

Comment: Hello RoVo, thanks for your comment. The problem is, that there is enough space in the one partition with my data - 300GB free. But the partition which has only the encryption files, is full. But maybe I can resize the partition, if I can't delete files there.

Comment: please add the output of `lsblk` to your question.

Comment: `df -Th` would show the type & used & available size (human) of the mounted partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/home/.ecryptfs/bianca/.Private` contains the encrypted versions of all your home files, when you're logged in they're decrypted on-the-fly to your home (`~` or `/home/bianca`). It should be approximately the same size as your home when you're logged in. Delete (or backup/move) some files out of your home, not directly from `/home/.ecryptfs/bianca/.Private` since it's probably not clear which home files they really are.

Disk Usage Analyzer / `baobab` is a tool I like, or just `du` (there are some commands to make it more readable & sorted, a web search or `man` has more info)